# what is the difference between merging B into A vs. A into B in git hub

Tags: git, github

I am starting to get the hang of git hub by using git hub for Mac. I noticed that the merge branches option lets you merge some branch, A into some branch, B. You could also do it the other way, merge branch B into some branch A. What is the difference? I found [this](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-branches) from the git hub documentation but it does not explain what I want to know.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's worth adding, here, that git's branch labels are not stored in the commits themselves.

Before getting into the rest, let's make a note about what a commit is, internally.  It's an entry that describes (in a complicated way) the stored version of an entire working-tree<sup>1</sup>, along with:

- the author and committer (name and email address)
- two time stamps (author and committer, again)
- zero or more "parent commits"

The "parent commits" are how you follow a branch's history.  "Regular" commits have a single parent, the previous commit from which the new work-tree was derived.  "Merge" commits have at least two parents, and a "root" commit has no parents: its tree was made up from nothing.

Git has a bunch of ways of naming any individual commit.  The "true name" is the SHA-1 hash, beginning with `9e17c4e` in the image in the question.  That name never changes, and in fact, it's a cryptographically-strong checksum of the entire contents of the commit.<sup>2</sup>

Those SHA-1 values are a pain to type, though (I try to cut-and-paste if I need them).  So there's usually another way to refer to a commit.  Git provides "branch" and "tag" names as a way to give them a meaningful name.  The `git branch` and `git tag` commands can create a new "reference name" for an existing commit.  A branch is simply a reference stored in `refs/heads/` (such as `refs/heads/master`), and a tag is one stored in `refs/tags/`.  (By storing these refs in a directory hierarchy like this, git also allows inventing new kinds of references in the future.  And in fact, there are already `refs/notes/commits`, used by `git notes`, and of course the "remote branches" stored in `refs/remotes/`.)

The primary (user-level) difference between a "branch" and a "tag" is that a tag is *supposed* to be permanent, and a branch is is *supposed* to move.  A branch—a reference in `refs/heads/`—is *automatically moved* when you add a new commit while you are "on the branch".  If you tell git to get on branch `B`, and then add a new commit to branch `B`, git makes the new commit, and then *moves the branch label* to the new commit.  If you like, you can think of the branch label as a sort of sticky-note, that git peels off and puts on the new end / tip of the branch.

This is exactly what [Cupcake illustrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18575869/1256452).  If you're "on branch `B`" and you `git merge A`, the merge adds a new commit<sup>3</sup> to B—specifically, a "merge commit", with two parent commits.  Then, since you're "on" the branch, git moves the branch label to the new commit.  Now the name `B` refers to the merge commit, with its two parents.

Similarly, if you're on branch `A` and you `git merge B`, the merge adds a new commit.  It's almost exactly the same commit—in fact, it has the exact same tree, and of course the same author and committer.  If you somehow manage to do this—in a parallel universe, perhaps :-)—at the exact same time, it even has the same time stamps.  But there is one other difference.  **Although the new commit will have the same two parents, they will be in the other order.**  And of course, git will then move the branch label, but the label this time is `A` rather than `B`.

**The parent order matters.**  Not very much, perhaps, and for "ordinary" commits, which have only one parent, there's nothing to order in the first place.  But they affect the SHA-1 checksum, and they also affect "parent traversal".  When following a branch backwards through this chain of parent commits, git has the notion of the "first parent", and various commands take a flag, `--first-parent`, to restrict parent-following.

Remember that the branch label really only labels one, single, commit: the one at the tip of the branch.  The set of commits "on" that branch is derived dynamically as needed, by following parents.  At a merge commit, where there are multiple parents, the branch can either contain *all* its parents—simultaneously following all of them backwards—or, for simple cases, just the *first* parent.  That way you find what was "on the branch" before the merge "brought in" everything on some other branch(es).

So, this is **why** (and **when**) **the order matters in a merge**: when you want to see what was "on the branch" "before" the merge, you can assume that following just the first parent gets you that.

(There are some wrinkles to this though.  In particular, a "fast-forward" merge does not create a merge commit, it just yanks the branch label "forward".  And, since branch labels are entirely "outside" the cryptographic checksum system, anyone can re-label any branch any time, and there is no record of this kept in the git repo.  There is a record in the "reflog", but reflog entries expire over time, and can be purged: they're meant for helping you fix up the mess if you accidentally shoot yourself in the foot, not for keeping you from being sneaky and confusing people.  But this is already too long and I have not gotten to my footnotes....)

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the commit tree records the contents of the *staging index*.  That's why you `git add` and `git rm` things, putting them "on stage" and arranging the tree the way you like, and only then `git commit` the staging index.

<sup>2</sup>The "contents" involve taking SHA-1 checksums of various parts, so this is partly a checksum of checksums.  I'm not a Cryptography Guy but I understand that generally reduces the cryptographic strength.  It's not so much meant for security, though.  These checksums are necessary to make git work at all.  If two different underlying git objects (files aka "blobs", trees, annotated tags, and commits) ever sum to the same value, git will break.

<sup>3</sup>This assumes a "nontrivial" merge that does not result in a "fast-forward".  Trivial merges occur when you merge a "feature branch" back into a "main branch" and no work has occurred on the main branch:

```
A--B                master
    \
     C--D--E        feature
```

If you just `git checkout master` and then `git merge feature`, git will notice that `master` is a "direct ancestor" of `feature`, because it's possible to start at commit `E` (the commit to which `feature` refers) and work backwards and reach commit `B` (the one you're "on" when you're "on branch master").  In this case, `git merge feature` will simply peel the label off commit `B` and paste it onto commit `E` instead.

To force a "real" merge, you'd still `git checkout master` so as to get on branch `master`, but then use `git merge --no-ff feature`, creating a new merge commit `M` with two parents:

```
A--B---------M      master
    \       /
     C--D--E        feature
```

The "first" parent, which you can now name by writing `master^` or `master~1`, is commit `B`.  The "second" parent, which you can now name by writing `master^2` or `feature`, is commit `E`.  Note that `master~2` refers to commit `A`: tilde-numbering follows the first parent.  (You can name commit `D` with the slightly awkward `master^2^` or `master^2~1`, and so on.  See the documentation for [git rev-parse](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) for even more ways to specify a revision.)

Answer (score 1):

If you merge branch A into B, only B's branch is updated to the new child commit, while if you merge branch B into A, then only A's branch is updated to the new child commit.

Here is what it would look like in graph form, starting out with unmerged branches:

```
---o---o A
    \
     o B
```

Now let's merge branch A into B (with `git merge A`):

```
---o---o A
    \   \
     o---o B
```

See how B is updated to the new child commit, while A remains unchanged?

Now let's see what happens if we try it the other way around by merging B into A (with `git merge B`):

```
---o---o 
    \   \
     o---o A
     B
```

In this case, A has been updated to the new child commit, while B remains unchanged. From here, you could also merge A into B, which will fast-forward B to be on the same commit as A:

```
---o---o 
    \   \
     o---o A, B
```

The order in which you merge might also affect which parent commit is considered to be the 1st vs the 2nd when using the `^` revision specifier:

1. `head^` and `head^1` both refer to the 1st parent of the child commit.
2. `head^2` refers to the 2nd parent of the child commit.

In terms of the commit graph, however, the order in which you merge makes no difference, you still end up with a child commit that points to two parents.

Comment: can you explain what a branch reference is. I just googled it w/o luck.

Comment: A branch is simply a reference to a commit. All branches are references, but not all references are branches (tags, for example). I'll update my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference.  If you merge A into B, A is unchanged and B will now have changes from branch A.

Comment: so if branch A has lines 1, 2 and then you make a branch of A called B and then you add line 3 to branch B ... then if you merge B into A it adds line 3 to A?

Comment: Yes in that case 3 is now a part of A.